# GUI for Build Process

Tags: user-interface, build

I've just implemented build and deploy process which consists of java files, ant script and cmd files. In the process, a release manager will have to check out source, hit the build.cmd button and then carry a zip file over to a server.

I am wondering if it is worthwhile to make a GUI for it? So that the release manager does not need to check out source manually for example?

How do I start? I have quite limited knowledge of javax, but I very much like to learn.

Thanks,

Sarah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like something that could be handled by [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).  It can check out source, run Ant scripts, etc., saving you the trouble of maintaining a GUI.  I'd give that a shot before rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

I have helped develop the build process at my current company. The way we currently do it is with a script file. It checks out the latest code from the stable branch of our repository, performs some steps to get some data from a database (such as static SQL data that needs to be loaded at deployment), then compresses everything. The file is then distributed to our production servers and then the setup routine is executed. Everything is automatic and the script is written in Python. Python is great for these types of things because of the sheer number of libraries it has to help the developer.

Perhaps it may be useful to build a GUI for your deployment procedure -- typically this would be useful if the deployment requires user interaction to make decisions, such as "Which server shall I deploy to?", etc. But, if it's just a matter of doing things automatically, then a script file's the way to go. Choose your favourite language and dive in -- I of course recommend Python.

If you'd like to learn how to make a simple GUI in Java (since that seems to be what your company is familiar with), you should check out the stuff at this site:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

I learned everything I know about Java from that site. The section on GUI programming is great.

Best of luck!

Shad

Comment: Thanks Shad. It's good to know how other companies are doing things. I am very happy to hear about Python is great for these types of things as I actually thought about using it although I know very basic things of it. The build process spec was written by someone else who suggested to use CMD file. I will try Python and if I can prove that it is better I will recommend it to my manager.